# Definir FROM diferente do e-mail que realmente está enviando. É seguro?

Tags: php, servidor, envio-de-email

Quando envio email através de php (phpmailer), posso configurar todos os parâmetros do email, no entanto, verifico que posso fazer algo do gênero:

```
<?php

  // Excerto do código
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->IsMail();
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

  $mail->Host = 'mail.meudominio.pt';
  $mail->Username = 'valid_user@meudominio.pt';
  $mail->Password = 'abc123';

  $mail->setFrom('emaildaminhavizinha@sapo.pt', 'pomba gira');
  $mail->addReplyTo('outroemailqualquer@yahoo.com', 'yahoo guy');

?>
```

Com isto, posso enviar um email autenticado, para qualquer pessoa, fazendo-me passar por uma 3ª pessoa.

**Questão:**
- Há hipótese de o meu servidor, obrigar a que o FROM seja igual ao email que faz a autenticação?

Comment: Return-path do email recebido tem o verdadeiro remetente

Comment: É o verdadeiro email ou poderá ser manipulado, tambem?

Comment: Nop, esse é o verdadeiro e não creio que dê para mudar (não tenho a certeza)

Answer (score 1):

Como você já deve ter notado, sim, é possível enviar normalmente.

Contudo, é uma má prática atualmente pois os servidores de e-mails estão bloqueando como uma questão de segurança básica.

Experimente, por exemplo, enviar para um e-mail do hotmail/live pois os servidores deles são bastante rígidos com isso. A tendência é outros serviços de e-mail seguirem isso como uma norma básica.

Portanto, defina o cabeçalho "FROM" exatamente igual ao e-mail que usou para enviar a mensagem.

Note que isso também é válido para e-mails não autenticados. Nesse caso, há outras normas básicas como um domínio válido, por exemplo.